# Passing a variable from JavaScript to PHP through AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, http-post, web-development-server

I'm trying to pass the a variable from JavaScript to PHP using AJAX, but I'm unable to do so. Whenever I try to var_dump($_POST['winner_id']) it returns NULL. I've tried to check the AJAX call with Developer Tools in Chrome and it showed  **winner_id:0** - which is right.

Here is my code:

## **JavaScript**

```
 function ajaxCall() {

   alert("To AJAX: the winnerid is: "+winner_id);

        $.ajax
        (   {


                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax.php",
                data: {winner_id : winner_id}, 
                success: function(response)
                { alert("The winner was passed!")}
            }
        );
};
ajaxCall();
```

## **PHP Code**

```
<?php 
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['winner_id']))

{
    $winner_id = $_POST['winner_id']."";
    var_dump($winner_id);
}

var_dump($_POST['winner_id']);

?>
```

If I do a `var_dump($_POST)` in the beginning of the PHP script then it gives me `array(0) { }`

I'm new to web development and have been trying to figure this out for hours now. Any hints would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Uhm, if you're passing an actual zero to PHP, what are you expecting back. Did you try this with some easily identifiable strings instead ?

Comment: Does `success` get called?

Comment: I initiate and calculate the winner_id before I call the ajax function and use the winner_id inside it

Comment: what is the possible values for `winner_id` in `$.ajax` `data`..?

Comment: yes, success gets called

Comment: possible values are 0-8

Comment: Just curious, may I know why are you concatenating a **""** in your `$winner_id = $_POST['winner_id']."";` ?

Comment: I took it out, now it's just : $winner_id = $_POST['winner_id']; The ajax is sending the value but I'm unable to get it in php.

Comment: Soory for commenting here but I used your code but the success message does not appear....Any ideas why..?I have posted a question also..If you want you can reply there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20773735/laravel-4-pass-data-from-view-to-controller-with-ajax

Answer (score 2):

Where are you intializing the winner_id.Either you have to pas it as an argument or intitialize it as aglobal variable.

```
function ajaxCall(winner_id) {

   alert("To AJAX: the winnerid is: "+winner_id);

        $.ajax
        ({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax.php",
                data: {"winner_id" : winner_id}, 
                success: function(response)
                  { 
                     alert("The winner was passed!");
                  }
        });
};
ajaxCall(winner_id);
```

Comment: Thank you Deepu! I followed the instructions you gave me, made sure that I pass in the winner_id as the argument for the function and I can see that it passes the result, however I'm still unable to get the   winner_id in my php code var_dump($_POST['winner_id'])= NULL

Answer (score 0):

Where did you initiate value to `winner_id`? like

```
function ajaxCall() {
var winner_id = '123';
...
```

or if you initiated `winner_id` before calling `ajaxCall()` ,you should call `ajaxCall()` with parameters like `ajaxCall($winnerid)`, which `$winnerid` is from your PHP
and then

```
function ajaxCall(winner_id) {
...
```

Comment: I tried to input the winner_id as a parameter for the ajax function and success was called, also as I went into the developer tools / network and XHR, it showed that the winner_id = 1 (which was right)

Comment: so if i suppose your initiated value is `$winnerid` just call function like `ajaxCall($winnerid)`.

Comment: Thank you Amir, the problem is that I'm still unable to get the winner_id in my php code: var_dump($_POST['winner_id'])= NULL

Comment: are you sure, your PHP code is in `ajax.php` at the same folder?

Comment: Yes, positive! Both, the javascript file and the php file are on my apache2

Answer (score 0):

i guess you have to convert your winner_id to a string because php read zero (0) as null

```
function ajaxCall() {

   alert("To AJAX: the winnerid is: "+winner_id);

        $.ajax
        (   {


                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax.php",
                data: {winner_id : winner_id.toString()}, 
                success: function(response)
                { alert("The winner was passed!")},
                dataType: "json"
            }
        );
};
ajaxCall();
```

Comment: Thank you for the winner_id.toString() idea. I implemented it, however I'm still unable to get it in my php script

Comment: Not necessary unless you are giving the response of ajax as json @Charlene Lauron

Comment: hmm but the function is passing json data to php, ok i'll test it.. thanks @Deepu